# On the uniform convergence of generalized integral

Tags: calculus, analysis, uniform-convergence

Is the integral

> $$ \int_{1}^{\infty} e^{-yx^2}\sin{y}dx.$$

uniformly convergent in $y \in [0,\infty]$? Why or why not?